# Hierarchical time series using DLM

Tags: time-series, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian, state-space-models, dlm

I am developing a forecasting solution using R's **dlm** package and it is proving to be very useful for most of our requirements.

However, I am also keen on sharing information among different time series in the form of hierarchical priors (think related product lines, markets, etc) and I was wondering if anyone has any thoughts as to how to do that with dlm?

I know that this might not be possible out-of-the-box, but does anyone have any thoughts as to whether this can be achieved through e.g. interfacing with Stan or any other way?